# Two form of derivative $ f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics

Why I can write formula derivative $$ f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ in this form: $$ f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(h)}{h}+O(h)$$
I know, that it's easy but unfortunately I forgot.

Comment: This follows from the definition of differentiability and the definition of Big-Oh notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ is equivalent to 
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h}{h} = 0$.

This in turn is equivalent to the function $g(h) = f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h$ satisfying  $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)}{h} = 0$.

Such a function is referred to as 'little o' or $o(h)$, and we say $g$ is 'little o' of $h$, or simply just write $o(h)$.

That is, we abuse notation and write $f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h = o(h)$, which gives rise to $f(x+h) = f(x)+f'(x)h + o(h)$.

**Note**: This is $o(h)$, not $O(h)$. The function $f(x) = |x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but we can write $f(h)=f(0)+0.h + O(h)$, but you cannot replace the $O(h)$ by $o(h)$, if you see what I mean.

Comment: ok, I understand why is 'little o' of h, but I still don't know why  why can replace this limes with o. Can you write me in words?

Comment: You can always (if differentiable at $x$) write $f(x+h) = f(x)+f'(x)h + g(h)$ for some function $g$. Instead of writing $g(h)$, the convention is to write $o(h)$ with the understanding that you are taking a notational shortcut.

Comment: Maybe I'm so stupid and I don't see answer, but why limes disappears ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'limes disappears'?

Comment: why we can hide $ lim_{h\rightarrow 0} $ and add $ o(h) $

Comment: You are not hiding anything. Writing $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)}{h} = 0$ is **exactly** equivalent to writing $g(h) = o(h)$. It is the definition of $o(h)$.

Comment: ok, now I understand :) thanks, but how I must check what is with $ o(h) $ if we calculate deravitive in traditional method?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. If a function is differentiable, then the first order Taylor approximation is $o(h)$ as above. If the first order Taylor approximation is $o(h)$, then the function is differentiable at the relevant point.

Comment: sorry, I mean, that I must show that "little o" is h :)

Comment: $ f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+o(h) $ this way ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: check what have "little o" inside (o(n) - we must find n), so I guess, that I should use Taylor series, like prev comment, right? And next $ \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{f(x)+hf'(x)+O(h^2)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)+O(h)$, it's true?

Comment: if it's true, in there should be big "O" or litte ?

Comment: It must be $o(h)$, not $O(h^2)$. It is **not** always true that $f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + O(h^2)$.

Comment: so maybe you have something else idea? to show, that is really $ o(h) $ ?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=|x|^{3/2}$. Then $f'(0)=0$. But $\dfrac{|h|^{3/2}-0}{h}$ is not $O(h)$.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of differentiability 
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+o(h),\,\,h\to{0}.$$
In your's second formula must be $o(1),$ not $O(h).$

Comment: Could you write something more :) ? Because I don't see this yet.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+\Big(f'(x)-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\Big)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+o(h)$, assuming $f'(x)$ exists (since $\Big(f'(x)-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\Big)$ goes to $0$ as $h\to 0$). It's true that if something is $o(h)$ it is also $O(h)$, so it's also true that $f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+O(h)$. Also if $g(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+o(h)$, then by taking $h\to 0$, we get that $g(x)=f'(x)$.